# Want to copy url from container and then use it as bg but I can't

Tags: javascript, css

So I have this code

```
$(function () {
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/u') == 0) {
var imgdefondo = $('#field_id2 dd.ajax-profil_parent div.field_uneditable').text();
//*****imagen de fondo*****//
$("td.row1 div#profile-advanced-details.genmed").css("background", "url('imgdefondo') no-repeat center");
}
});
```

It's supposed to copy the text in the container named "Imagen de portada:" which should be an image and then use it as the background image of "td.row1 div#profile-advanced-details.genmed", but it doesn't work with my code, I tried a couple of javascript checkers and they said that the variable "imgdefondo" is unused, how do I modify the code to make it work like I want to?

Hope you can help me

Webpage: http://evolvelatam.foroweb.org/u1

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `imgdefondo` is not a variable, it is part of a string. You need to do some concatenation.

```
$("td.row1 div#profile-advanced-details.genmed").css("background", "url('" + imgdefondo + "') no-repeat center");
```

Comment: Well what is the text in the variable `console.log(escape(imgdefondo))` ?

Comment: the text should be picked from a container in the webpage, here it is 'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3946/15610912156_9b90fd6cfe_o.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not treat imgdefondo as a variable properly, see this working code example, which takes the URL in the "sample" div, and makes it the background of the "bg" div.

```html
<div id="sample">http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-9.jpg</div>
<div id="bg" style="border:1px dotted black;width:320px;height:320px"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var imgdefondo = $('#sample').text();
     $("#bg").css("background", "#f00 url("+imgdefondo+") no-repeat center");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you but it did't work, perhaps the javascript my webpage uses is old? I created the forum as phpBB2 in forummotion

Comment: Make sure you have the http:// in front of your url.  If necessary, use:      $("#bg").css("background", "#f00 url(http://"+imgdefondo+") no-repeat center");